# ng-style syntax in controller

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this line in my `html` and I want to be able to change the style from the `controller`

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-2x" ng-click="$ctrl.decrementPage()" ng-style="leftArrow()" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I have a class defined for the controller but I can't seem to get the syntax right for changing the style of the element. This is what I have so far:

```
public leftArrow = () => {
        'color': '#0095FF',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
}
```

I'm getting an error for the `:` where it says `;` was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
leftArrow = function() {
    return {
        'color': '#0095FF',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
   }
}
```

```
<i ng-click="$ctrl.decrementPage()" ng-style="$ctrl.leftArrow()"></i>
```

Comment: I can't use `$scope` since this is in a class that I defined for the controller.

Comment: @johnmurphy Updated

Answer (score 1):

`private`, `public` or `protected` keywords aren't there in current [ECMAScript 6 specification](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html). That is what throwing an error if your are using ES6.

```
leftArrow = {
    'color': '#0095FF',
    'cursor': 'pointer'
};
```

**HTML**

```
ng-style="$ctrl.leftArrow"
```

Answer (score 0):

use variable leftArrow, not function

```
 $scope.leftArrow={
    'color': '#0095FF',
    'cursor': 'pointer'
 }
 ...
 ng-style="leftArrow"
```